# Spring security with user/password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

So I followed some guides on spring security with usernames and passwords, however most of them show using "InMemoryUserDetailsManager" which they say should not be used in production:

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager(){
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("ADMIN")
            .password("123")
            .roles("ADMIN").build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
}
```

My questions, so how should a production level version of this be setup? Is it just not using the default password encoder because it is deprecated or should I use an entirely different method of adding and storing users?

Comment: The latter. You should probably use the JDBC version or your own `UserDetailsManager` instead.

Comment: So I should replace the method that stores the users, but the way of creating users is fine? Perhaps you have a blog or doc link that goes into detail about this

Comment: No that way isn't usable for production, how would you add user? Modify code, redeploy? What if a user needs to change its password? Modify code and redeploy?

Comment: so if I changed the hardcoded values to be pulled from a database, would the method itself be good enough, or should I also change it?

Comment: What method? The declaration of the users? No it isn't. You would want to use SQL or a management interface to modify users in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement jdbc authentication `DaoAuthenticationProvider`. Checkout https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-jdbc-authentication.

Your user details must be stored in permanent storage, not temporary storage. Also, passwords must be encrypted to avoid compromising security. So using permanent storage you can take backup or data and run queries out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom user details service instead of using default.

```java
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user == null) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.NOT_FOUND, "user");
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.getEnabled(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                getAuthorities(user));
    }

    public Boolean isTokenValid(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claimsJws = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException | MalformedJwtException | UnsupportedJwtException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.LOGIN_FAILURE, "invalid credentials");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.LOGIN_FAILURE, "token expired");
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public Boolean save(User user){
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getUsername())) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.BAD_REQUEST, "username");
        }

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getPassword())) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.BAD_REQUEST, "password");
        }

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(user.getEmail())) {
            throw ApiExceptionFactory.getApiException(ApiExceptionType.BAD_REQUEST, "email");
        }

        User registeredUser = new User();
        registeredUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        registeredUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        registeredUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        registeredUser.setEnabled(true);
        registeredUser.setRoles(user.getRoles());

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(registeredUser);

        Inventory userInventory = inventoryService.saveInventoryForUser(savedUser.getUsername());

        return userInventory != null;
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user){
        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        for(Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName().getRole());
            authorities.add(grantedAuthority);
        }
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

You can save user details into your repository.

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);

}
```

Finally add your user details into authentication manager with password encoder.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl(userRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

For more details check my [github repository](https://github.com/oktaykcr/bom-app-be/blob/master/src/main/java/com/oktaykcr/bomappbe/security/WebSecurityConfig.java)

Answer (score -4):

Hello Please Code as the following coding

```
@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager createUserDetailsManager() {
    
    UserDetails userDetails1 = createNewUser("username1", "dummy");
    UserDetails userDetails2 = createNewUser("username2", "dummydummy");
    
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails1, userDetails2);
}

private UserDetails createNewUser(String username, String password) {
    Function<String, String> passwordEncoder
    = input -> passwordEncoder().encode(input);

    UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                                .username(username)
                                .password(password)
                                .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                                .build();
    return userDetails;
}
```

Hope it help you

Comment: Could you elaborate how separating the User creation with a new method makes it better?

Comment: It working code I take reference from  [Click this](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-master-class/blob/master/02.Spring-Boot-Web-Application-V2/Step38.md)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).